# Value with a comma in bootstrap-progressbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

progressbar

http://www.minddust.com/project/bootstrap-progressbar/demo/bootstrap-3-3-4/

and I can not in any way to enter into the bar in the chart with a percentage point. eg. 12,34 but always puts me and only 12.
someone has had the same problem or can give me a little help.

Hello and thanks

Giuseppe

Comment: Javascript only supports floating numbers using the `.` for the decimal point. Use the `replace()` method to change the `,` to a `.`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to display formated percentage value you should not use provided `percent_format` as it is already rounded to whole number.
Use `amount_format` and set `use_percentage` to `false`.

Due to limitations of the library you use you **have to** multiply current and max value by the `10 ^ desired precision`. For example in order to display 2 decimal digits of 76.23% set `data-transitiongoal="7623"` and `aria-valuemax="10000"`

Then implement `amount_format` as `function(p, t) { return (p / t * 100).toFixed(2) + ' %'; }`

[See the fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/pu4pmmzc/)

Above example can be implemented this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.progress .progress-bar').progressbar({
    display_text: 'center',
    use_percentage: false,
    amount_format: function(p, t) {
        return (p / t * 100).toFixed(2) + ' %';
    }
  });
});
```

For the HTML part please note multiplied values by 100:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" data-transitiongoal="7623" aria-valuemax="10000"></div>
</div>
```

In order to convert a number to string with n digits of precision you can use [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method.

If you want to display that number with a comma instead of a dot as a digits separator you can use `replace('.', ',')` method on the result string.